# Science Fiction book about space heat laser

Tags: story-identification, books

The details I remember are that there's a satellite above Earth that shoots invisible heat rays at earth in a somewhat small circular area (perhaps a few dozen meters). for whatever reason the satellite goes rogue and starts randomly shooting its rays. This results in a scenario where a person sees it boiling the ocean as it moves closer to him and then he gets burned too. That's about all I can recall.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?  What is this satellite for?  Who put it in orbit?

Comment: One of Asimov's Donovan & Powell robot stories, [Reason](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reason_(short_story)), had this as the potential consequence of the apparently-rogue robot not letting them focus the microwave emitter correctly, -but it didn't actually happen.

Comment: *Energized* by Edward Lerner, and *PowerSat* by Ben Bova both involve energy emitting satellites that get hijacked, but I can't find any references to a scene with a boiling ocean approaching someone.

Answer (score 2):

My best guess for this would be ***[Sunstroke](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1590058.Sunstroke)*** (1993) by David Kagan.

> A new energy source--a satellite that coverts the sun's energy into microwaves and beams them directly to earth--becomes a potential instrument of doomsday when its failsafe controls malfunction.

Unfortunately, I have long since lost the book and can't find any excerpts. But the plot is centered on a satellite which is a solar power station that beams its energy to a ground station via microwaves, and then gets knocked into an uncontrolled orbital path. There are a number of scenes depicting this doom of focused microwave energy approaching / overtaking people.